# Advice on learning email API authentication and JSON in python3

Tags: json, python-3.x, api, email, python-requests

Best solver or fellow problemized,

**The context:**
The reason I’m asking this question is that I am trying to learn how to automate clinking links in emails with python3. I’ve gone in depth on how to achieve this with selenium but without success. I’ve just heard that this could be possible with API.

I've been trying to find a documentation or explanation for the past 2 hours on how to use something like AHEM - Ad-Hoc Temporary Email Server’s API.  https://www.ahem.email/help/api

An hour ago I didn’t know anything and now I know how to call json API with requests and an authentication key. yay me...

**The problem:**
Now I need to get an authentication token but it asks for content type string and a request body. I’m lost. I’ve used google and youtube but I can only find gmail, reddit and hackernews API documentations which are not much alike I think.

I'm sorry for the vague description of the problem that, quite honestly, resembles my knowledge about the subject. More clarity could be achieved by following the link and taking a look at General: General APIs > POST > Get access token.

**The solution?**

Does anyone know a good book, video or just plain advice?

**Thank you so much in advance!**
**I hope the answer is not on the front page of Google if you get what I mean.**

Comment: "but it asks for content type string and a request body" - is there a place in the documentation when this is specified? In general there are many ways to get access tokens, from oauth processes, HTTP basic auth to just obtaining it in some kind of dashboard.

Comment: @mfrackowiak, well there is a bearerAuth (http, Bearer) button where you have to insert an unknown value. After you enter something there it says you're "authorized" but that does not really change anything. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the job.

```
import requests

base = 'https://www.ahem.email'

url = f'{base}/api/auth/token'
respone = requests.post(url=url)
if respone.status_code == 200:
    token = respone.json()['token']

    bearer = f'Bearer {token}'
    header = {'Authorization': bearer }

    url = f'{base}/api/alive'
    print(requests.get(url=url, headers=header).json())
```